# Adding a CSS class is not rendered by the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, backbone.js

I have the following code (Backbone view, rendering using Handlebars):

```
_this.$el.addClass("loading");

_this.el.innerHTML = _this.template({
    some: data
});

_this.otherCPUConsumingRenderingFunctions();

_this.$el.removeClass("loading");
```

The CSS class displays a "Loading" message on screen to warn the user, since rendering takes time due to a large amount of data and a complex rendering.

My problem is that the CSS class is correctly applied (I see it in the inspector) but nothing is displayed on screen.
If I put breakpoints and go step-by-step, it will work perfectly.

The issue occurs both with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: The jQuery is correct. It seems the class is not being applied. Check the CSS paths and syntax.

Comment: What exactly `otherCPUConsumingRenderingFunctions` is? Does it do anything asynchronous? You state it works step-by-step, so it simply happens so quickly that you do not see it :).

Comment: Thank you Alvaro for your quick reply. As I've mentioned, the CSS works just fine: I use it in other cases and step-by-step debugging renders perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you'll need to use a callback after the rendering function completes. Also remember expensive rendering operations, depending upon their design, can be blocking — meaning the dom does not get a chance to re-render until all the work is done. In this case it will add the `loading` class and remove it all before the dom redraws. Stepping through your code provides the browser time to re-render which is why you'll see it working when debugging.

Perhaps something like this

```
_this.otherCPUConsumingRenderingFunctions = function (callback) {
    // do work here
    callback();
};

_this.$el.addClass("loading");

_this.el.innerHTML = _this.template({
    some: data
});


// You can use a timeout to "schedule" this work on the next tick.
// This will allow your dom to get updated before the expensive work begins.
window.setTimeout(function () {
    _this.otherCPUConsumingRenderingFunctions(function () {
        // Ensure this only runs after the rendering completes.
        _this.$el.removeClass("loading"); 
    });
}, 1);
```

The [backburner.js](https://github.com/ebryn/backburner.js) project was created to help mitigate this kind of problem. It works well with Backbone too.

Comment: It does actually work, thank you (though I need to put at least a 100ms timeout for it to be effective...)

Comment: I get the feeling that you misunderstood the answer (if you need to put 100ms for the solution to be effective)

Answer (score 1):

No rendering function in browsers is synchronous. So your `otherCPUConsumingRenderingFunctions` is most probably returning as soon as you call it. It does it's thing later asynchronously.

That is why your loading class gets removed as soon as it is added.

Comment: I have tried to put console.log(Date.now()) all around the place and timing looks good. But if you have ways to add callbacks, I would gladly appreciate :)

Comment: You need to paste the details of your rendering function first

Comment: Oh BTW, I forgot to mention, the class is added and removed at the correct time. Since the rendering takes a few seconds, I can see it in the inspector.